# Use grep with exact match for list from a file

Tags: unix, grep

I'm trying to search for an exact match for a set of patterns within a file.

I've tried:

```
    grep -w -f IDs.txt seqs.txt > output.txt
```

But I'm missing some of the patterns.

Example:

```
IDs.txt
denovo23
denovo28
denovo62
denovo897
denovo621
denovo622

seqs.txt
denovo23    HNS.2_9729  HNS.2_20867
denovo28    HNS.6_14948 HNS.6_148211    HNS.11_327521
denovo62    HNS.7_468475    HNS.7_631780
denovo897   WNA.2_58410 WNA.1_175071
denovo621   WNA.2_20180 WNA.2_294219
denovo622   CES.1_24310 HNS.6_26786
denovo637   HNS.2_262147
denovo586   HNS.1_332240
```

Expected output:

```
denovo23    HNS.2_9729  HNS.2_20867
denovo28    HNS.6_14948 HNS.6_148211    HNS.11_327521
denovo62    HNS.7_468475    HNS.7_631780
denovo897   WNA.2_58410 WNA.1_175071
denovo621   WNA.2_20180 WNA.2_294219
denovo622   CES.1_24310 HNS.6_26786
```

Actual output:

```
denovo23    HNS.2_9729  HNS.2_20867
denovo28    HNS.6_14948 HNS.6_148211    HNS.11_327521
denovo62    HNS.7_468475    HNS.7_631780
denovo897   WNA.2_58410 WNA.1_175071
```

So I need a way to do an exact match of the pattern within a list in a file.  I've seen several ways to do the exact match but none that work with a list in a file - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Works fine in my Debian & Bash 4.4 & gnu grep 2.27 - What is you bash/grep version and your OS?

Comment: I'm using Bash 3.2.57 and BSD grep 2.5.1, on Mac OS 10.11. Thanks!

Comment: I also get the expected output (bash 4.2.25 and grep 2.10 from Ubuntu 12.04).  Maybe you really have too old tools which stumble over something in your input.  Check for trailing spaces in IDs.txt, for example.

Comment: People have been reporting various bugs with this grep version in Mac OS : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352977/why-does-this-bsd-grep-result-differ-from-gnu-grep . I think GNU grep is available for installation in MAC repos - may be you need to install it

Answer (score 0):

Your `grep -w -f` command works fine either on my Debian Testing & Bash 4.4 & GNU grep 2.27 or even in my FreeBSD11 VM with Bash 4.4 and BSD grep 2.5.1.
I can not find what is wrong with your system causing grep to fail.

In the meantime you can do the same job with awk (tested in both Debian with gnu awk and FreeBSD with non gnu awk):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a' ids.txt seq.txt
```